# Select query Null

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and have a select query that I am trying to create a Null column in.

The query is being used to create a tab delimited text file to be imported by a different system. I am using

```
Select data1 as col1, data2 as col2, '' as col3, data4 as col4
```

The problem apparently is that the other system does not see Col3 as NULL even though when I open it in Notepad++ it shows a NULL in that column.  The vendor says there is something in that column.  I assume they are seeing it as an empty string and not null.

What is a different/better way to put that NULL column in?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
Select data1 as col1, data2 as col2, NULL as col3, data4 as col4 FROM tamble_name
```

Comment: We tried the "NULL" as col before and they said no, hence we went with empty string/null

This is what I just received from them..
They said there was specific characteristic NULL code with 1 byte.
Are there any ways to put  really “Nothing” (0byte) in place of that NULL code with 1 byte ?

Comment: @user2941811: Don't use `'NULL'"` but `NULL`. `NULL` means _undefined_ as opposed to an empty string `''` or the string `'NULL'` which are clearly defined.